# How to link main with made libraries?

Tags: c, libraries, modularization

I'm trying to link libraries I made to main source code, but it throws this error. I've been searching for last two hours how to fix this but nothing worked for me.

Compiling:

```
cd "c:\Users\miros\OneDrive\Documents\C codes\labovi"
gcc 01main.c -o 01main
.\01main
```

> d:/programs/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\miros\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGHtHKg.o:01main.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to 'faktorijel'
> d:/programs/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\miros\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGHtHKg.o:01main.c:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to 'suma'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

01ucitavanje.h

```
#ifndef UCITAVANJE_H
#define UCITAVANJE_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long long *niz;
int n;

void ucitavanje();
#endif
```

01ucitavanje.c

```
#include "01ucitavanje.h"

void ucitavanje(){
    scanf("%d", &n);
    niz = malloc(sizeof(long long) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", niz + i);
}
```

01izracunavanje.h

```
#ifndef IZRACUNAVANJE_H
#define IZRACUNAVANJE_H
#include <stdio.h>

long long faktorijel(int n);
long long suma(long long *niz, int n);

#endif
```

01izracunavanje.c

```
#include "01izracunavanje.h"

long long faktorijel(int n){
    long long f;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        f *= i;

    return f;
}

long long suma (long long *niz, int n){
    long long s = niz[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        s += niz[i];
    return s;    
}
```

main.c

```
#include "01izracunavanje.h"
#include "01ucitavanje.h"

int main(){
    ucitavanje();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        niz[i] = faktorijel((int)niz[i]);
    printf("%d", suma(niz, n));
    free(niz);
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: How are you building/linking?

Comment: [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

Comment: I'm running it just the way I would run one .c file, meaning I'm trying to start main.c.

Comment: Have a look at this guide
https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/C-C-plus-plus/GCC/create-libraries/index

Comment: You generally need to tell the linker how to find your libraries.  Often, this would entail passing `-l` flags to the tool chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're compiling only main.c into the executable, so the other functions aren't available.

You need to compile each source file into an object file, then link the object files together.

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -c 01izracunavanje.c
gcc -c 01ucitavanje.c
gcc -o 01main main.o 01izracunavanje.o 01ucitavanje.o
```

Comment: I did what you said here but program still doesn't run. Anything else to do?

Comment: @qu4lizz Define "doesn't run".

Comment: I mean nothing happens.

Comment: @qu4lizz So when you compile the program there's no output?

Comment: Yeah, even when I run .exe file, nothing.

Comment: @qu4lizz That's a different problem.  Time to do some debugging.

Comment: LMAO, I didn't have any output before input, so that's reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to give you a mid-line correction because you put your compilation on one very long line.

In this case, you pass all your `.c` files to `gcc`. From

```
{ gcc 01main.c -o 01main }
```

We'd rather write

```
{ gcc -o 01main 01main.c 01izracunavanje.c 01ucitavanje.c }
```

Since you're not actually building a distribution library but rather a bunch of source files we just compile them all together. It generates better code that way anyway once you start optimizing.

Order of `.c` files doesn't really matter, but the file containing `main` is first by tradition. Putting `-o` before the first `.c` file used to matter and most people still do it.

Comment: How to run program after doing this?

Comment: @qu4lizz: I'm confused. Why is your `.\01main` not correct.

Comment: Everything's right, I made a little mistake. Thanks anyway.